# A property does not exist in type "Interface"?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, interface

I am new to Typescript. I am trying to use interface as an array type. I structure my literal object by order, though I still get this error  :

> Type '{ id: number; title: string; image: string; words: string;
>   description: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IWordList[]'.
>   Type '{ id: number; title: string; image: string; words: string;
>   description: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IWordList'.
>       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'IWordList'.

**Notice that the case isn't about 'id' itself, but it is if I added any addtioal property, I get the same error**

IWordList.ts

```
export interface IWordList{
    id : number;
    title : string;
    image : string;
    words : string;
    description : string;
}
```

wordlistsdata.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IWordList } from './IWordlist';

@Injectable()
export class WordlistsdataService {

  constructor() { }

  private allWordLists : IWordList[] = 
  [
      {
          id : 1,
          title : "Animals",
          image : "/src/app/images/wordlists/animals_background.jpg",
          words : "cat,elephant,cow,duck",
          description : "sdadasd"
      },
      {   
          id : 2,
          title : "Jobs",
          image : "/src/app/images/wordlists/jobs_background.jpg",
          words : "engineer,farmer,artist,programmer",
          description : "sdadasd"
      }

    ]

  public getWordList() : IWordList[]{
    return this.allWordLists;
  }

  public getOneWordList(id : number) : string[] {
    return 
  }
}
```

Comment: How does the component code look like that uses this data?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), can you? What version of typescript are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If someone stumbles upon this error i recently get this with webpack dev server and hot moduel reloading. Only solution that works:

Restart webpack dev server so it compiles from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I just copied your code into a Plunker and it worked just fine. You can see my code here: https://plnkr.co/edit/sxcYl5v5jBlfzZ31fHLd?p=preview

See if you can run it from there as well.

Ah ... but this tool requires that I paste the code ... even though you have it above ... so here is the AppModule:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  providers: [ WordlistsdataService ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed my code by this time. Instead I will read the data from local json file. It's more convenient.By the way, I loved your course "Angular 2 : Getting Started" on Pluarsight. You are phenomenal author. Keep up posting Angular 2 courses; I am loving your teaching way.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please have a look at this question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567722/typescript-angular2-rxjs-missing-property-but-its-already-exist ) I tried to create a similar component to the product-detailsa from the course. But I am facing a poroblem with my service. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It was showing up in my build watch but not in Linter, which detects those errors. So I decided to restart the build, and got a new error, pointing to a case where I had created an object without the property that was throwing the error (in your case "id"). Interestingly, Linter had missed that actual error. I fixed this code so that "id" was being defined, and started the build once again. This time it worked with no errors.

Answer (score -3):

Try with this:

```
export interface IWordList{
    id ?: number;
    title : string;
    image : string;
    words : string;
    description : string;
}
```

The `?` operator allows you to make things optional.